# Call query which displays odata information with ajax

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, odata

I have following query

```
    [WebGet]
    public IEnumerable<Table> Query1()
    {
        var Context = new ProjectEntities();
        var First = new DateTime(2012, 10, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0);
        var Last = new DateTime(2012, 11, 5, 17, 0, 0, 0);
      return 
            Context.Table.Where(
                s =>
                s.Date > First && s.Date < Last &&
                Context.Table2.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID ==1).Table3.Contains(s.Table3)).ToList().Take(20);

    }
```

Table contains 3 `Foreign Keys` , `'Table3_id'`, `'Table5_id'`, `'Table6_id'` and as you can see, my query returns a list of `Table` entities.

My Ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#b7").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:port/Ctx/Query1",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (item) {
                if (item.Table5!= null) {
                    $("#t7").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + item.Table5.Title + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Table3.Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Date + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                     });

        }
    });
});
```

My call is wrong because it returns nothing ( or `undefined` ).

**How can I call that query ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Create an interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyQuery
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<Table> Query1()
}
```

Then inside your service (.svc)

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Table> Query1()
{
  var Context = new ProjectEntities();
        var First = new DateTime(2012, 10, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0);
        var Last = new DateTime(2012, 11, 5, 17, 0, 0, 0);
      return 
            Context.Table.Where(
                s =>
                s.Date > First && s.Date < Last &&
                Context.Table2.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID ==1).Table3.Contains(s.Table3)).Take(20).AsQueryable();

}
```

• The operation must be a public instance method that is a member of the data service class.

• The operation method may only accept input parameters. Data sent in the message body cannot be accessed by the data service.

• If parameters are defined, the type of each parameter must be a primitive type. Any data of a non-primitive type must be serialized and passed into a string parameter.

• The method must return one of the following:

- IEnumerable
- IQueryable
- An entity type in the data model that the data service exposes.
- A primitive class such as integer or string.

• In order to support query options such as sorting, paging, and filtering, service operation methods should return IQueryable. Requests to service operations that include query options are rejected for operations that only return IEnumerable.

• In order to support accessing related entities by using navigation properties, the service operation must return IQueryable.

• The method must be annotated with the [WebGet] or [WebInvoke] attribute.

- [WebGet] enables the method to be invoked by using a GET request.
- [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")] enables the method to be invoked by using a POST request. Other

WebInvokeAttribute methods are not supported.

Inside your javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#b7").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost/your service.svc/Query1?$format=json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d, function (i) {
                if (data.d[i] != null) {
                ...
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

if this did not help try following the following [quick start guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668796.aspx)